# Need help! React Component Export not working >_<

Tags: reactjs

> Im having this issue where even though I'm exporting both components
>   `SearchBar` & `MainCard` I keep getting this error message in my
>   `App.js` file. Any feedback is appreciated!

Error: 
`./src/App.js - Attempted import error: 'MainCard' is not exported from './components/ui-componets/SearchBar'.`

> App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Theme } from '@customLibrary/core'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchComponent } from './actions';
import TopMenu from './components/ui-componets/TopMenu';
import {SearchBar,MainCard} from './components/ui-componets/SearchBar';



class App extends Component {

  state = {
    visible: true,
    width: 13,
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible, width: 16 })
  }
  render() {

    const { userData } = this.props;
    const { visible } = this.state;

    return <Theme>
      <Container width='3379px'>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </Container>
      <Container width='3379px'>
        <TopMenu onClick={this.handleClick} userData={userData} />
      </Container>
      <Container width='3379px'>
        <SearchBar />
      </Container>
      <Container width='3379px'>
        <MainCard/>
      </Container>
    </Theme>
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    userData: state.user
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchComponent })(App);
```

> SearchBar.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { IS_FETCHING_DBUSERS, FETCH_DBUSERS_SUCCESS, IS_FETCHING_ROLES, FETCH_ROLES_SUCCESS, IS_FETCHING_RESOURCES, FETCH_RESOURCES_SUCCESS } from '../../actions/keys';
    import { users, Roles, Resources } from '../../actions/URI';
    import { fetchComponent } from '../../actions/index';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import _ from 'lodash';


    import {
        Theme,
        Grid, Form, Icon, Container, Loader,

        Card, Typography, Tabs
    } from '@customLibrary/core';

    class SearchBar extends Component {
        ...
    }

    class MainCard extends Component {
       ...
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {

        return {
            Users: state.users,
            roles: state.roles,
            resources: state.resources,
        }
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchComponent })(SearchBar,MainCard);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {SearchBar,MainCard} from './components/ui-componets/SearchBar';
```

You have used default export while exporting, but using the syntax for named imports while importing.

```
import CustomName from './components/ui-componets/SearchBar';
```

should work

Comment: Thank you for your input! Ive tried doing that after reading up on similar issues but that just renders the SearchBar component twice. This is what I did, in my App.js I added these two imports instead (in hopes to render both the searchBar and MainCard) `import SearchBar from './components/ui-componets/SearchBar';
import MainCard from './components/ui-componets/SearchBar';` but it just renders searchBar twice

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** You've not correctly exported `MainCard`, and you export them as a default export (i.e. only *one* component is exported), but you import them as named exports.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchComponent })(SearchBar,MainCard);
```

**Solution:** From what I know, the `connect` HOC can only decorate a single component at a time. If you want to export both then you'll need to connect both individually as named exports (i.e. remove the `default` keyword.

```
export const ConnectedSearchBar = connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchComponent })(SearchBar);
export const ConnectedMainCard = connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchComponent })(MainCard);
```

Now the import in `App` will work

```
import { SearchBar, MainCard } from './components/ui-componets/SearchBar';
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I tried that previously but I kept getting a `Parsing error: Only one default export allowed per module.` it doesnt like it when I have two exports in the same file

Comment: @CatGirl19 True, you can have only ***one*** default export, but you can have any number of named exports. Try it again without *any* default exports.

Comment: doing it the way you had it gives me a `Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)` so after I added the default to the `SearchBar` export statement only the second export statement is giving an error of `Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)`

Comment: @CatGirl19 Yeah, OFC, sorry, I said to use a named export and I forgot to name the exports. Please see updated answer.